# Disable scrollbar while preserving scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm stack on trying to disable html scrollbar while preserving the scrolling and keeping the scrollbar of text area. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eb28r/1/)

I've tried to set this:

```
html {overflow:hidden;}
```

it worked partially butI'm not satisfied with that so do you have any perfect solution?

thanks.

Basically I dont want two scrollbar...

Comment: Here's a fiddle which already has a lot of text in it: http://jsfiddle.net/eb28r/2/. If you set `overflow: hidden` on this element, how are you intending to see the text at the bottom?

Comment: any idea on what i'm talking about?

Comment: Users like scroll bars, they inform the user that the page or element *does* scroll.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't afraid of plugins, iScroll may be the perfect solution. This is made to simulate scrolling like known from mobile devices and can transform any element to scrollable areas and also provides options to hide the scrollbar when you're not scrolling. Here, check this example (but you really can hide the scrollindicators even if not shown there):

**[simple iScroll demo](http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/)**